# JavaScript :TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript

Following is my code.

```
<html>

<head>
<script>
    var x = 5;
    var y = 6;
    var z = x + y;
    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = z;
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Demo</h1>
<div id="demo">Addition of 5 and 6 is <span id="add"></span>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

And when I am trying to display the value of z in (span add) I am getting following error.

```
 TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

Please help me.

Comment: just move the `script` block at bottom of page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the order : put the script after the element so that it's defined when `getElementById` is called.

```
<body>
    <h1>Demo</h1>
<div id="demo">Addition of 5 and 6 is <span id="add"></span>
</div>
<script>
    var x = 5;
    var y = 6;
    var z = x + y;
    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = z;
</script>
</body>
```

Another solution would be to use jQuery's `ready` function :

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var x = 5;
        var y = 6;
        var z = x + y;
        $('#add').html(z); // if you use jQuery, you may as well do that
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Demo</h1>
<div id="demo">Addition of 5 and 6 is <span id="add"></span>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: If ever there was a need for an FAQ, then this question (and ones about *this* in callbacks) are a very good argument why there should be one.

Comment: The reasons boil down to: 1. element doesn't exist yet, 2. no element with that ID exists at all, 3. capitalisation wrong (subset of 2).

Answer (score 4):

Add your code to onload event like this

```
window.onload = function () {
    var x = 5;
    var y = 6;
    var z = x + y;
    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = z;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/luqeyo/1/edit?html,output

Because you try call document before it ready to use.

**Update:** if you don't want wait, while will load all resources (images etc.) you can use this approach

```
  document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
      ready();
    }
  }

  function ready() {
      var x = 5;
      var y = 6;
      var z = x + y;
      document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = z;
  }
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/luqeyo/2/edit?html,output